# Segmentation Fault in C while loop to populate array

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, bin

The file is a .bin file. When calling function in the terminal, the program opens the file and the segmentation faults. Have I mixed up one of my types or maybe not used a pointer properly? Any help is much appreciated, thank you for taking a look

````
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Student bank[20];
    FILE * rfile;
    Student *pStudent;
    int i=0, n,  end, count=0;
    float graded;
    char *stufile, name[256];
        
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        stufile = (char *)malloc(MAX_NAME+1);
        printf("What file would you like to open? ");
        scanf("%s", stufile);
        if (stufile ==NULL) return 1; 
    }
    else{
        stufile = argv[1];
    }
    // open file
    rfile = fopen(stufile,"rb");
    if (rfile == NULL){
        printf("File not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n\n%-20s %-10s %10s\n","Name", "E-mail", "Grade");
        printf("------------------------------------------\n");

        fseek(rfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        end = ftell(rfile); // will get to the EOF returning a int
        fseek(rfile,0,SEEK_SET); // set cursor back
// I think this is seg fault??
        while(fread(&bank[i++], sizeof(Student), 1, rfile) == 1){
            if(feof(rfile)) break;
            ++count;
        }
        fclose(rfile);
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<count; ++i){
            // print student info
        printf("%-20s, %s %-10s %d%%\n",  bank[i].lastName, bank[i].firstName,
        bank[i].emailAddress, bank[i].grade);
        n = n + bank[i].grade;
    }
    graded = n/count;
    printf("Average Grade:\t\t%.2f", graded);   
    return 0;
}```
Good news no longer seg fault now it is printing off[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZKAW.png
````

Comment: `fread(&bank[i++]` Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. Look at the variable values. Specifically consider what is the value of `i` when it crashes?

Comment: You have too many moving parts in that `while` loop.  Separate the condition (the return value of the `fread`) from the assignment `&bank[i++]`, and make the assignment to a temporary variable first, not to an array element whose index is being incremented in-transit.  Doing these things will make your code much easier to reason about and to debug.

Comment: `while(fread(&bank[i++]...` `i` is uninitialized here. You should also be aware that `fgets(stufile, MAX_NAME, stdin);` will leave the newline at the end of the filename which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Well, `i` is not initialized, and on top of that you're not even checking the bounds when doing `bank[i++]` anyway... so that's two reason for a possible segfault there.

Comment: You're also trying to accumulate the grades but doing so incorrectly, accessing `bank[i].grade` *after* you've incremented `i`.

Comment: I have moved bank[i].grade thank y'all for all the information I no longer have a seg fault. I have not figured out how to run the debugger on this program and I am unseure on how to do it in the terminal. in VS code it says there is no .bin file but if i terminal I do get some information now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `i` in `&bank[i++]` without initializing it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).